# XAML PathGeometry Relative Positioning (m not M)

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, path

I am trying to replicate a square I drew with (Path) by using (PathGeometry). I want to move this square around based on its starting position, and let the rest render relative to that. But I can't figure out how to replicate the "m" property of (Path.Data) this way, it does for some reason I don't get automagically use "M". Anyone that could educate me on how to fix this? Google does not really distinguish between "m" and "M".

Original Path (Square):

```
<Path Stroke="Red" Data="m 15 250 70 0 0 90 -70 0 z"></Path>
```

And this is the alternative I am trying to get to work (which apparently makes it easier to move the full square by binding the starting point to a value I control).

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="15,250">
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                        <LineSegment Point="70,0" />
                                        <LineSegment Point="0,90" />
                                        <LineSegment Point="-70,0" />
                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
```

Comment: Geometry coordinates are always relative to the coordinate system of the Path element. The lowercase letters in path markup syntax are just a convenience and coordinates are immediately converted while the geometry is parsed. You may however move the Geometry by setting its Transform property, or move the Path by setting its LayoutTransform or RenderTransform property. Or put it in a Canvas and set Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top.

Comment: Are you sure Geometry coordinates are always relative to the Path Element? Because I have the same coordinates, and one is a square while the other (the PathGeometry) looks like a crooked arrow pointing down on the square.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. For the first move command it shouldn't matter anyway if you use m or M. There is nothing that you could move relative to.

Comment: Thing is I want the PathGeometry to draw a square based on the principles of using the m rather than the M in the first example. Is there any property I can use to enforce PathGeometry to render its Lines relative to the previous point rather than by absolute coordinates?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Well guess I got my answer then, so I have to find another workaround. Thank you.